# Image recognition game automation with Python. I want it to work on the full screen

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a program using an image-in, but I can't enter the game cover separately, but I don't think it't even if you can't even find itWhat should I do to find images in the entire screen, how should I do it automatically?

I've tried many things, but it doesn't work when it's full screen

Comment: Full screen games on Windows tend use DirectX to take full ownership of the frame buffer, so the Windows desktop (which you are reading) is not available.  Partly, they do this to avoid the kind of cheating you are attempting.